# transportar dados para outra página

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estou fazendo o frontend de um sistema de login e estou usando javascript puro para isso. Eu já consigo logar na API e no console do browser receber os dados do usuário que está logando. Este é meu AJAX:

```
function loga() {

 console.log("Enviando post");

 let usuario = {


email: document.querySelector("#email").value,
senha: document.querySelector("#senha").value
};

let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http:web/rest/logins", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {

console.log(xhr.responseText);

if( xhr.status == 200) {

  window.location="interno/index.php";
} 

if(xhr.status == 500) {

  var dadosInvalidos = document.querySelector('#dados-invalidos');
  dadosInvalidos.classList.remove('invisivel');
}
});
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(usuario));

}
```

Os que me aparecem no console são o id e o restante dos dados do usuário. O que preciso saber agora é como faço para transportar o id do usuário para a página inicial, ou seja, a página que vem depois que o usuário faz o login, e assim conseguir montar o perfil do usuário nela. Como consigo fazer isso? Alguém pode me ajudar? Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Da uma olhada em `sessionStorage`: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: Então @MaxRogério sou meio leigo e ainda não consigo ler documentações, por isso estou usando o Fórum. Você sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Não tem nada a ver com a sua dúvida mas, se me permite uma opinião: Passar usuário e senha via http não é uma boa ideia! Já pensou em encriptar usando uma chave pública e decriptar no servidor? Eu geralmente faço isso usando a jsencrypt.

Comment: Então... eu só desenvolvo forntend,  desenvolvo para uma API JAVA criada por meus sobrinho, e nem sou desenvolvedor frontend a muito tempo, na verdade nem sei o que é jsencrypt, mas obrigado pela dica, vou procurar saber o que é

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode transportar as informações entre as páginas utilizando tanto `sessionStorage` como `localStorage`, mas ambos tem comportamentos diferentes. O `sessionStorage` mantém as informações enquanto a aba/janela do browser permanecer aberta, enquanto o `localStorage` mantém as informações mesmo após o navegador ser encerrado.

Ambos podem ser criados utilizando o método `setItem()`, ex.:

```
`sessionStorage.setItem("chave", "valor");`
```

Para obter o valor armazenado pode utilizar o método `getItem()`, ex.:

```
sessionStorage.getItem("chave");
```

Caso precise armazenar objetos complexos, você pode utilizar o `JSON.stringify()` para armazenar e depois o `JSON.parse()` para recuperar o valor, ex.:

```
var obj = { a: "1", b: "2" };
sessionStorage.setItem("meuObj", JSON.stringify(obj));
var objRecuperado = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("meuObj"));
```